# how to produce large number of lines with a script that will run as interactive commands

Tags: bash

I need to emulate interative command input.
I tried this:

```
$ for ((x=1;x<500; x++)); do "#"$x; done
```

I expect this behavior:

```
bash: #1: command not found
...
...
bash: #499: command not found

$ history
1 for ((x=1;x<500; x++)); do "#"$x; done
2 #1
3 #2
...
500 #499
501 hisotry
```

but instead I see only the script line appeared in history output, not the individual "#"$x lines.

```
bash: #1: command not found
...
...
bash: #499: command not found

$ history
1  for ((x=1;x<500; x++)); do echo "#"$x; done
2  hisotry
```

I guess the reason being is the commands commands are run in sub-shells hence won't show up in the history of "this" shell.

any idea to make it happen?

Comment: Since `echo "#"$x` is program *output*, why would you expect that to show up in history? Why not `for ((x=1;x<500; x++)); do echo "#"$x; done > mytmpfile && history -n mytmpfile && rm mytmpfile`?

Comment: See [script(1) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html)

Comment: I expect to see each line of the  mytmpfile appear as a command in history output as if they were entered interactively. "history -n mytmpfile" does not add each line of the file to history. when I type history command, only "history -n mytmpfile" itself is shown.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "echo" before what you want printed.Try this:

```
for ((x=1;x<500; x++)); do echo "#"$x; done
```

Hapy coding.

Comment: I tried that before and it didn't work. it printed "#"$x lines instead of running them as commands. there is only the script itself in history.

Answer (score 0):

I`m not understanding what you want to achieve. Do you want just a cascade of "#"1, "#"2, "#"3..."#"499? Like this one?
[image]